# Which result is more reliable in NMaximize in the given code? with `WorkingPrecision` or without it?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, mathematical-optimization, precision-and-accuracy

I have two functions $ f(x,y) $ and $ g(x,y) $ over the domains $ 1<x< 2$ and  $0<y<\pi$. I use `ContourPlot` to ses those values of $(x,y)$ for which $g(x,y)=0$ assuming that $f(x,y)>1$

```
f[x_, y_] :=  Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x];
g[x_, y_] := (3 Sin[3 x])/(2 x) +  Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/ x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x])^2];

ContourPlot[  g[x, y] == 0 , {x, 1,2}, {y, 0, Pi}, FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y},   f[x, y] > 1]]
```

I get this plot

[image]

**Question**

> Using `With[{y = Pi},   NSolve[g[x, y] == 0 && 15/10 < x < 16/10 && f[x, y] > 1, x]]`
> and as can be seen in the plot, we know that there is no solution at $y=\pi$. I want to calculate the MAXIMUM value of $1 < x < 2$ which the blue curve tends to; in other words to calculate the MAXIMUM value of $1 < x < 2$ which satisfy the conditions $g(x,y)=0$ and $f(x,y)>1$ over the mentioned domain of $0<y<\pi$.

Using `NMaximize` without `WorkingPrecision`, I get

```
NMaximize[{x, g[x, y] == 0, f[x, y] > 1,  1.56 < x < 1.6  , 3 < y < Pi  }, {x, y}]

(* {1.57079, {x -> 1.57079, y -> 3.13717}} *)
```

when I increase the precision, the result changes; for `WorkingPrecision->10`, I get

```
NMaximize[{x, g[x, y] == 0, f[x, y] > 1, 1.56 < x < 1.6 , 3 < y < Pi }, {x, y}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]

(* {1.569235375, {x -> 1.569235375, y -> 3.012529257}} *)
```

for `WorkingPrecision->20`, I get this error

```
NMaximize[{x, g[x, y] == 0, f[x, y] > 1, 1.56 < x < 1.6 , 3 < y < Pi }, {x, y}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(*  NMaximize::precw: The precision of the argument function ((3 Sin[3 x])/(2 x)+Sqrt[-1+(Cos[Times[<<2>>]]+2 Power[<<2>>] Sin[<<1>>]+Plus[<<2>>] Csc[<<1>>] Sin[<<1>>])^2]==0&&Cos[3 x]+(2 Sin[3 x])/x+(Cos[2 x]-Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x]>1&&1.56<x<1.6&&3<y<\[Pi]) is less than WorkingPrecision (20).
NMaximize::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.
{1.5695423462418012228, {x -> 1.56954, y -> 3.02596}} *)
```

Which result is more reliable? How can I get rid of the error that occurs as `WorkingPrecision` increases?

Comment: For your last question, the numbers in `1.56 < x < 1.6` are machine precision, less than your `WorkingPrecision`, and the source of the ***warning***. It's not an error exactly, just a warning that your input is inconsistent.  Use ``1.56`20`` or `156/100` instead of `1.56` and so forth.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The warning still persists.